# Adding custom html into Html.MenuItem link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I use [Html.MenuItem helper](http://supremeware.blogspot.com/2011/03/showing-selected-menu-item-in-mvc.html) in asp .net mvc. I want to use html inside link instead of text only. The helper below:

```
@Html.MenuItem("Announcement", "Index", "Announcement")
```

generates in html =>

```
<li> <a href="/Announcement">Announcement</a> </li>
```

but I want to generate an html like =>

```
<li> 
     <a href="/Announcement"> 
           <i class="icon-announcement"></i> 
           <span>Announcement</span> 
     </a>
</li>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that immediately, because the HTML gets stripped if you pass it in as the parameter.
I suggest you do something like the following:

```
<li> 
     <a href='@Url.Action("Announcement", "Index")'> 
           <i class="icon-announcement"></i> 
           <span>Announcement</span> 
     </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can't I do that with using an html helper like in this site: http://supremeware.blogspot.com/2011/03/showing-selected-menu-item-in-mvc.html

Comment: Definitely, if you want to use this often then that's the right approach. If you're only using it in once place, then you should probably not bother with an HTML-helper.

Comment: Then, how can I do this with an Html Helper?

Comment: No, it generates only text inside link.

Comment: Well, you'd have to adjust the code for what you need. The post explains the principle, you'd have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I can do that I think, but I wonder is there any easy way for accepting linkText as html.

Comment: If you run into any issues, feel free to post a new question and we'll be happy to help.